Android Emulator WiFi Limited Connection Issue after macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 Upgrade
I recently upgraded my macOS to Sonoma 14.4.1 on an Apple M2 laptop and have encountered an issue with the Android emulator's WiFi connection. The emulator shows a limited WiFi connection, and I'm unable to establish a stable internet connection.
I have tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

Restarted the emulator.
Checked and re-entered the correct WiFi network settings on the emulator.
Restarted network services on the emulator.
Ensured my host machine (Mac) has a stable internet connection.
Updated the Android emulator and SDK to the latest versions.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Are there any additional steps I can take to resolve this problem? Could the macOS upgrade have caused compatibility issues with the Android emulator's network settings?
